# Grails 3 : is spring-security-ldap going to get updated? Does it need to?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, spring-security-ldap

So [grails-spring-security-core](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/) was updated for grails3, but not [spring-security-ldap](http://grails.org/plugins/spring-security-ldap) yet. Is it going to ? Is it needed? 
I guess the beans configuration in `SpringSecurityLdapGrailsPlugin.groovy` cannot be done in another 'spring boot magic' way ?

Answer (score 1):

I started to upgrade it and it's mostly finished, but there are a couple of failing tests. I think they're false failures, related to the ldap plugin and the gldapo library. I'll work on this some more over the weekend. If you send me an email I'll make the updated plugin available to you so you can test it and validate that it works like the 2.x plugin.

Comment: Great. Didn't realize I was that cutting edge :)

Comment: Burt, in case my email to you went to the spam box, my email is my nickname at gmail.com.

Comment: I also need to migrate a grails 2.3.4 to 3 and I am using the spring security core and the spring security ldap for authentication. I think i found the core here https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/org.grails.plugins%3Aspring-security-core/view#files/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core but where is the ldap one? Thanks!!

Comment: The core plugin group changed, so the 3.0.0.M2 release is at https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.0.M2/view, and the ldap plugin is at https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-ldap/3.0.0.M1/view